# Can distortion be derived from inertia rather than recalculating it from scratch in case of kmeans?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I got this definitional difference between distortion and inertia from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-with-k-means-1e07a8bfb7ca#:%7E:text=Distortion%20is%20the%20average%20of,to%20their%20closest%20cluster%20centre.):

> Two values are of importance here — distortion and inertia. Distortion
> is the average of the euclidean squared distance from the centroid of
> the respective clusters. Inertia is the sum of squared distances of
> samples to their closest cluster centre

However, when I searched for an example from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/elbow-method-for-optimal-value-of-k-in-kmeans/):

```
distortions.append(sum(np.min(cdist(X, kmeanModel.cluster_centers_,
                                        'euclidean'), axis=1)) / X.shape[0])
```

I took one inertia value from:

[image]

and 1 distortion value from :

[image]

however the values 217.64 and 3.45 aren't simply a division of 217.64 by count of variables in x (17).

Can anyone detail on what exactly is the formula for distortion?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that

```
distortions.append(sum(np.min(cdist(X, kmeanModel.cluster_centers_,
                                        'euclidean'), axis=1)) / X.shape[0])
```

does not square the distance as stated in the definition

> Distortion is the average of the euclidean **squared** distance from the centroid of the respective clusters

If you replace

```
    mapping1[k] = sum(np.min(cdist(X, kmeanModel.cluster_centers_,
                                   'euclidean'), axis=1)) / X.shape[0]
```

with

```
    mapping_squared[k] = sum(np.square(np.min(cdist(X, kmeanModel.cluster_centers_,
                                   'euclidean'), axis=1))) / X.shape[0]
```

you will get the desired result:

```
IN: for key, val in mapping_squared.items():
    print(f'{key} : {val}')

OUT:  
1 : 12.802768166089965
2 : 4.025210084033612
3 : 0.954621848739496
4 : 0.7467787114845938
5 : 0.5647058823529413
6 : 0.42156862745098034
7 : 0.29901960784313725
8 : 0.24019607843137258
9 : 0.16666666666666669
```

That is, the values in `mapping_squared` can be multiplied by the number of samples to match inertia:

```
IN: np.array(distortions_square) * X.shape[0]

OUT:
array([217.64705882,  68.42857143,  16.22857143,  12.6952381 ,
         9.66666667,   7.51666667,   5.66666667,   4.08333333,
         3.        ])
```

On a side note: Distortion and SSE are usually used interchangeably. See, for example, the paper [Scaling Clustering Algorithms to Large Databases](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/KDD/1998/KDD98-002.pdf):

> Distortion is the sum of the L2 distances squared between
> the data items and the mean of their assigned cluster

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87950/distortion-function-for-k-means-algorithm) touches the subject too.